# OpenCV in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, opencv

I want to use opencv in windows phone and not sure if any support available for that. any link / sample code would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can't. WP7 only supports managed code, OpenCV is native library.

You have 3 options:

1. Target WP8 instead.
2. Some companies (e.g. Tango, Spotify) somehow convinced Microsoft to allow native code development for WP7 platform.
3. Look for alternatives to OpenCV, such as AForge.NET.